# Sudoers - Execute command without sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I have this rule in my sudoers file

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/supervisorctl
```

Now I can run the command without root password.

For example :

```
sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

My question is How can I run the command without sudo command ?

For example :

```
supervisorctl restart all
```

Comment: SO is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can ask on [ubuntu.se] instead.

Comment: It has been argued on SO many times, that shell scripting *is in fact* "programming". And although `sudoers` file might seem foreign to windows users as if it were an OS only thing, it's no different than an Apache configuration file,  `php.ini` file, or a `my.cnf` file.  It contains parameters that say, a `shell` or `bash` script may use in order to function properly.  That said, there may be cases where a `php`, `python` or `java` script may need to run as `sudo`.  Points 6  and 7  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) covers this as this could be a bash or shell command.

Comment: It's entirely possible OP did not include the rest of a bash or shell script, as to provide a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --  Opting for the word "Minimal"

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make that work by setting the sticky flag:

```
sudo chmod +s /usr/bin/supervisorctl
```

You can try this out using `whoami`:

```
cp /usr/bin/whoami /tmp/whoami2
sudo chown root:root /tmp/whoami2
sudo chmod +s /tmp/whoami2
```

If you then run `./tmp/whoami2` as any user, you'll get `root`, i.e., the executable executes as the user with owner, given the sticky flag.